# How does stacking help Bias and Variance?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, ensemble-modeling, ensemble, stacking

How does stacking help in terms of bias and variance?
I have a hunch that stacking can help reduce bias but i am not sure, could someone refer to a paper?

Comment: I dont think there is a definite answer to this..